# Adding external datraframe data, via substring filter, to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python noob here. Big respect to you all. Hope you can help.

I have two pandas dataframes, `df1` and `df2`:

`df1`:

|  | style_gid | style_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1202357372219055 | DIA |
| 1 | 1202357372219056 | WVU |
| 2 | 1202357372219057 | GWE |

`df2`:

|  | project_gid | project_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1202318051699659 | Project Master |
| 1 | 1202318100865244 | TEST-DIA-LON-1 |
| 2 | 1202320766191762 | TEST-WVU-LONMUN-1 |
| 3 | 1202381389399069 | TEST-DIA-MUN-2 |
| 4 | 1202381389399070 | Custom Section |

And I have tried so many things, so many. I need to work out how to check `project_name` in each row of `df2` to see if it matches with one of the `style_name` entries from `df1`. If that's true, to then *somehow* bring the `style_name` and `style_id` into `df2`, like in the below table.

The rules are that if the text in `style_name` is found *anywhere* in the text in 'project_name', that's a match and so that project should be assigned the relevant style.

For example, the project names above contain two examples of matches with 'DIA', and one example of a match with 'WVU':
TEST-**DIA**-LON-1
TEST-**WVU**-LONMUN-1
TEST-**DIA**-MUN-2

The dataframe of styles is a moving target, the list will change values and number of entries for `style_name` (i.e. we may end up using others 'ABC', 'XYX', whatever as well), but the search will always be for 3-letter strings, in capitals.

Anything that doesn't match a style gets a null or none, or 'Potato', I don't mind, I can handle that later.

**I cannot work out** how to perform this lookup/insert, despite finding several solutions to test the name. Please can someone help?

So the resulting dataframe `df2` ends up looking like this:

|  | project_gid | project_name | style_gid | style_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1202318051699659 | Project Master | None/Null | None/Null |
| 1 | 1202318100865244 | TEST-DIA-LON-1 | 1202357372219055 | DIA |
| 2 | 1202320766191762 | TEST-WVU-LONMUN-1 | 1202357372219056 | WVU |
| 3 | 1202381389399069 | TEST-DIA-MUN-2 | 1202357372219057 | DIA |
| 4 | 1202381389399070 | Custom Section | None/Null | None/Null |

Or to a new dataframe, just so long as each project gets the style it deserves.

Comment: loop through df1.style_name and test with df2.project_name.str.contains(""). When you do that or another approach, provide your code and the people here would be able to better help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that we are always looking for the *first* match of the pattern `ABC` preceded by one `-` and followed by another `-` (So, never "LON" in "TEST-DIA-**LON**-1"), we could implement the following steps:

1. add column to `df2` with RegEx match (or not) extracted from `df2.project_name`;
2. check if these matches exist in `df1` (redundant, if you can be certain of this);
3. `df2.merge` to add `df1.style_gid` (and rearrange the cols to match your

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# we have 2 dfs: df1 (style), df2 (project)

# regex to capture first match of pattern like 'ABC' preceded by '-' and followed by '-'
pattern = r"(?<=-)([A-Z]{3})(?=-)"

# use str.extract() to populate new col with all found matches
df2['style_name'] = df2['project_name'].str.extract(pattern)

# lambda to ensure that all your matches actually exist as 'ABC's in df1, else 'NaN'
df2['style_name'] = df2['style_name'].apply(lambda i: i if i in list(df1.style_name) else np.nan)

# merge on df1 to get matches for df1.style_gid
df2 = df2.merge(df1, how='left')

# rearrange last two cols
df2 = df2.iloc[:, [0,1,3,2]]
```

output `print(df2)`:

```
    project_gid       project_name     style_gid style_name
0  1.202320e+15     Project Master           NaN        NaN
1  1.202320e+15     TEST-DIA-LON-1  1.202360e+15        DIA
2  1.202320e+15  TEST-WVU-LONMUN-1  1.202360e+15        WVU
3  1.202380e+15     TEST-DIA-MUN-2  1.202360e+15        DIA
4  1.202380e+15     Custom Section           NaN        NaN
```

Comment: thank you so much. Your code has definitely got me over the line on this one.

What's notable here for me is the use of str.extract(), which I had failed to even consider. 

I'd been barking up the wrong tree with str.contains(), struggling to work out how to get it to create a new column if it found a match, and been trying to merge the dataframes without success as I lacked a common column... so that's awesome!

I didn't explain the rules for a match clearly enough, as you got the wrong end of the stick there, but it doesn't matter as I can amend the regex to suit.